# Clarification on the process of finding torsion coefficients (invariant factors)

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, torsion-groups

I think I'm doing this correctly but I wanted to check. I'm trying to find the torsion coefficients - sometimes called the invariant factors - of the group Z/9 * Z/14 * Z/6 * Z/8.

I start by finding the elementary divisors of each number by breaking them up into prime powers - i.e., I separate each number into its divisors until i have either prime numbers or a number that is a power of a prime.

This gives me 9, 2, 7, 2, 3, and 8 as the elementary divisors, which I then group by prime bases to get 2,2,8, 3,9, and 7.

To finish, I multiply together the largest number of each group, then second-largest in each groups, etc., until all the numbers are used. This gives me 504, 6, and 2 as my torsion coefficients

Comment: Yes, you are doing this correctly.