# Is there any difference between invariant factors and torsion coefficients?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups

I'm working on Elements of Algebraic Topology of Munkres. Exercise 3(d) in page 26 requires to find the torsion coefficients and invariant factors of a finite abelian group $G$. I've never seen definitions of invariant factor, but according to some references like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701480/clarification-on-the-process-of-finding-torsion-coefficients-invariant-factors), torsion coefficients and invariant factors seem to be exactly the same things, but I'm not sure.

Comment: They come from different decompositions of $G$.  The torsion coefficients will divide each other $t_1 | t_2 | \cdots | t_k$ where $Tor(G) = T_1 \times \cdots \times T_k$ with $|T_j| = t_j$.  Whereas the invariant factors are all powers of primes; you write $Tor(G) = \mathbb{Z}/(p_1^{\alpha_1}) \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/(p_m^{\alpha_m})$ for not-necessarily-distinct primes/powers.  Both are decompositions into cyclic groups.  You can switch from one to the other easily; if you make your question more specific then you might get a more involved answer.

Comment: I think your comment is enough and has completely solved my problem, thank you @JohnSamples